# Environment variable with spaces in a string - How to use them from /proc/pid/environ

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, nsenter

I set a variable with spaces in a string to a new bash:

```
VAR='my variable with spaces' /bin/bash
```

And now if I want to start a new bash with the same environment, I would do something like:

```
ENV=$(cat /proc/self/environ | xargs -0 | grep =)
env -i - $ENV /bin/bash
```

But the thing is, in `/proc/self/environ`, this variable is without quotes. So the last command throws a: `env: variable: No such file or directory`

How can I work around this limitation?

PS: this is a simplified version of the following issue: https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter/issues/62

Comment: are you sure you need to do that? Processes started from a process inherit the invoking process' environment.

Comment: Take a look at the link github issue to understand why this question is being asked.  The end goal is to start a shell inside a Docker container that has the same environment variables available as PID 1 in the container.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer here is to not use a shell script to set things up.  Using a higher-level language makes it much easier to parse `/proc/<PID>/environ` into something useful.  Here's a short example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import argparse


def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('pid')
    p.add_argument('command', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
    return p.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()

    env = {}
    with open('/proc/%s/environ' % args.pid) as fd:
        for envspec in fd.read().split('\000'):
            if not envspec:
                continue

            varname, varval = envspec.split('=', 1)
            env[varname] = varval

    print env
    os.execvpe(args.command[0], args.command, env)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Put this in a file called `env-from`, make it executable, and then you
can run:

```
env-from <pid> bash
```

And you'll get a shell using the environment variables from the
specified process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time on this, but it's a bit sad to add such a big dependency (python) to do something that looks like easy. I think I'll use sed or awk to do the same.

Comment: So, write it in C or go and compile it.  I bet that both sed and awk will be problematic, too, especially when it comes to dealing with variable contents that contain quotes and such.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-L1` to `xargs` (max non-blank input lines per command line):

```
xargs -0 -L1 -a /proc/self/environ
```

This will give you each variable on a separate line, which makes it easier to process. Or simply use

```
strings /proc/self/environ
```